# Do the laws of witnesses apply to members of a bait din?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court, kerovim-close-relatives

Do the laws restricting witnesses based on their relation to other parties in the case or based on their past sins apply to the judges of a bait din?

Eg. Can a father and son serve together? May a compulsive gambler? I've learned these are invalid as witnesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shulchan Arukh CM 7:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x8712)

> **כל הפסולים** (*להעיד*) **מחמת קורבה או מחמת עבירה -- פסולים לדון**
>
> ‏*(ועיין לקמן סי' ל"ג ול"ד פרטי הפסולים לענין עדות וה"ה לענין דיינות שהדיינים לא יהיו קרובים זה לזה ולא לעדים) (ר"ן פ"ב דכתובות ותשובת רשב"א סי' תש"ץ) (עיין לקמן סי' ל"ג סעיף י"ז):*‏

In short, the same rules apply. All who are invalid to testify due to being related or due to sins they've committed are invalid to judge as well. See more rules about who is Kosher to judge there in Choshen Mishpat Siman 7.